# Determine limit superior and limit inferior of the following sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have been given the sequence $\lbrace x_n \rbrace_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, where $x_n = (-1)^n \frac{1+n}{n}$ and have been asked to determine the limit superior and limit inferior.

My problem is that it seems as if $\sup \lbrace x_n \rbrace_{n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq k} = x_k$ for $k$ even and $\sup \lbrace x_n \rbrace_{n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq k} = x_{k+1}$ for $k$ odd. I don't see how I can use this to determine the above.

Any help?

Comment: "I don't see how I can use this to determine the above" Well, simply compute the limits of $x_k$ for $k$ even and of $x_{k+1}$ for $k$ odd. Their maximum is the limsup you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\frac{1 + n}{n} = 1 + \frac{1}{n} \geq 0$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n = \lim_{k \to \infty} x_{2k} = 1$$ and $$\liminf_{n \to \infty} x_n = \lim_{k \to \infty} x_{2k + 1} = -1$$

Comment: Of course! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the subsequences $x_{2k}=1+{1\over 2k}\to 1$ and $x_{2k+1}=-1-{1\over 2k+1}\to -1$ and you have the two limitis you're looking for